# Rss feeds: get certain amount of tweets

Tags: rss, count, feed

Is it possible to give a parameter when getting the RSS feeds to determine how many feeds it should get?

I don't want to load all the RSS feeds, but only the first 20. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Give *what* a parameter?

Comment: Which RSS feeds? What do you want to limit, exactly? When you say "feeds", do you actually mean "items"? What URL is the feed you're talking about? (If it's a standard Twitter RSS feed you're asking about, try just adding `&count=20` on the end; Twitter's API for RSS feeds normally limits based on the `count` parameter.)

Comment: Not twitter, just any rss feeds, doesn't really matter what link. I was wondering if it's possible to put a parameter behind the RSSFeedsLink like &count for getting tweets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the limit. By executing a Loop in limit. So it will parse the xml and your program will read items in loop. Once the loop crossed the limit. Just break the loop.

```
$i=0;
while ($reader->read()) {

if($i>=10)
       break;
else{
switch ($reader->nodeType) {

case (XMLREADER::ELEMENT):

if ($reader->localName == "item") {

$node = $reader->expand();

$dom = new DomDocument();

$n = $dom->importNode($node,true);

$dom->appendChild($n);                           

$sxe = simplexml_import_dom($n);

$url = (String)$sxe->url;
$title=(String)$sxe->title;
}

}
}
```

In the above code $i is the limiter. Where we can limit number feed to display in the page.